# How can I get the positional parameters, starting from two, or more generally, `n`?

Tags: shell, variable, array

> ($@) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.

How can I get the positional parameters, starting from two, or more generally, `n`?

I want to use the positional parameters starting from two, as arguments to a command, for example,

```
myCommand $@
```

Comment: Do you want to preserve 1 to n positional parameters?

Comment: I am not sure. Can I ask for both cases?

Comment: as an array? as `$@` but shifted `n` ?

Comment: @Jeff: if used as an array, will need shifting so that the first entry in the array is the nth position parameter. It is possible they are not used as an array,

Comment: Note that it almost never makes sense to leave `$@` unquoted.

Answer (score 13):

For positional parameters starting from the 5th one:

- `zsh` or `yash`.

  ```
  myCommand "${@[5,-1]}"
  ```

  (note, as always, that the quotes above are important, or otherwise each element would be subject to split+glob in `yash`, or the empty elements removed in `zsh`).
- `ksh93`, `bash` or `zsh`:

  ```
  myCommand "${@:5}"
  ```

  (again, quotes important)
- Bourne-like shells (includes all of the above shells)

  ```
  (shift 4; myCommand "$@")
  ```

  (using a subshell so the *shift* only happens there).
- csh-like shells:

  ```
  (shift 4; myCommand $argv:q)
  ```

  (subshell)
- `fish`:

  ```
  myCommand $argv[5..-1]
  ```
- `rc`:

  ```
  @{shift 4; myCommand $*}
  ```

  (subshell)
- `rc`/`es`:

  ```
  myCommand $*(`{seq 5 $#*})
  ```
- `es`:

  ```
  myCommand $*(5 ...)
  ```

Answer (score 7):

```
$ foo=(1 2 3 4)
$ echo "${foo[@]}"
1 2 3 4
$ echo "${foo[@]:0:2}"
1 2
echo "${foo[@]:2}"
3 4
```