# pipe one or more PIDs from pgrep into top's -p argument

Tags: linux, process, top, command-substitution

I saw this nice question:

[Pass the output of previous command to next as an argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108782/pass-the-output-of-previous-command-to-next-as-an-argument)

and tried to get what I wanted from it but no luck.

I often want to watch my maxima/lisp process and instead of running top/htop/etc I thought I could just search for "maxima.core" and use the pid returned from that search as input to the "-p" flag for top. If it returns more than one, it is not so big of a deal.

1.) If I know the PID, I can use this:

```
top -p 10815 -o S -d 0
```

2.) To get the PID(s) I do this:

```
ps -fu <user> | pgrep -f maxima.core
```

which outputs a list like,

```
10814
11989
```

*But* trying to concatenate them fails for me. My tries have mostly centered around this:

```
<user>@<user> ~ $ top -o S -d 0 -p $(ps -fu <user> | pgrep -f maxima.core)
```

Also tried to incorporate the results of this: [How can I get the positional parameters, starting from two, or more generally, `n`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351901/how-can-i-get-the-positional-parameters-starting-from-two-or-more-generally)

```
top -o S -d 0 -p "${(ps -fu <user> | pgrep -f maxima.core)[@]}"
```

but it complained of poor substitution.

I pretty much rely on bash.

Comment: Does your version of `pgrep` support a `-d` (`--delimiter`) option? BTW I doubt piping `ps -fu <user>` into `pgrep` is doing anything - you probably should use pgrep's own `-f` and `-u` options

Comment: aahhh you are right, ps was nothing. Yes, my pgrep supports delimiter - it is from procps-ng 3.3.10. I also know that top's -p will take a comma separated list of PIDs.

Comment: so does `top -o S -d 0 -p "$(pgrep -d, -u <user> -f maxima.core)"` do the trick?

Comment: yes! it works great - thanks! if you make it an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your version of `pgrep` supports the `-d` (`--delimiter`) option, you should be able to use that to provide a comma-separated list of PIDs to `top`:

```
top -o S -d 0 -p "$(pgrep -d, -u <user> -f maxima.core)"
```

Comment: `-d` (not `--delimiter`) should be fairly portable as it was already there in the original implementation on Solaris 7. If not, you can always pipe to `paste -sd, -`.

Comment: Note that `maxima.core` also matches on `maxima-core` (it's an extended regexp). Use `'maxima\.core'`  to match on `maxima.core` only (anywhere in the process argument list).